# Paragraph :hover not working properly in Chrome

Tags: html, css, webkit

I created a `<p>` css rule but it's not working properly in Chrome.
In Edge, the behavior of the `<p>` rule is correct:

- By default, the paragraph is a block element and hover triggers when I put the mouse on it, regardless the amount of text on the `<p>`
- In Chrome, I need to put the mouse on the `<p>` text to trigger the `:hover` pseudo-class

  .hidden-controls .control{
      display: none;
  }

  .hidden-controls:hover .control{
      display: inline-block;
  }

So given this HTML code:

```
<p class='table-row elegant hidden-controls'>
    ✔&nbsp;{{name}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <input type='button' onclick='RemoveStakeholder(0);' class='pretty small-font-size control vertical-align-middle' title='Remove' value='Remove' />&nbsp; 
    <input type='button' onclick='EditStakeholder(0, this);' class='pretty small-font-size control vertical-align-middle' title='Edit' value='Edit' />&nbsp;
    <input type='button' onclick='MoveStakeholder(0, "M" );' class='pretty small-font-size control vertical-align-middle' title='Move to missing' value='✖' />
</p>
```

In Chrome, it only triggers when I put the cursor on the text. Is there a fix or workaround? Or is this just a issue with webkit?

I tested this with explorer and Edge and it works fine.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/afnchaz7/3/

Comment: If I make a Snippet using your code, the hover triggers when I'm anywhere within the line of the paragraph.  Can you include a Snippet in your question that shows the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: Sure, I created this: https://jsfiddle.net/afnchaz7/3/

Comment: So... I'm noticing this has to be an issue with table-row display. If I surround the <p> element inside a <div> and add the .table-row rule to the div, it fixes the problem... Weird lol

Comment: Note that `display: table` does not necessarily take the whole width of a line.  Add a border, and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in behavior for Chrome or Firefox. In both cases paragraph  gets squeezeв by "display:table" property. Just remove them and you will get a full line.

Comment: Not really. In Edge it takes full width and cannot remove table to the parent, it's not the only row I use. I solved it by sorrounding the <p> in a <div> and set the div to table-row

Comment: Sorry I can't understand your problem. Glad you fixed it.